# What's the correct way to import a symbol from another font compatible with XeLaTeX/LuaLatex?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math, font-encodings

EDIT: Apparently I wasn't very clear since I **linked the question this supposedly duplicates in the first sentence so I could ask about the robustness of that solution.**.  I want to know if the method described there is something I can count on to be robust across various engines XeLatex, pdflatex, lualatex and something that won't break by running out of the math alphabets.

I should have been more clear and simply said:  Is the method used in [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) the right way to do it in a package that might be used under multiple different engines.

---

I want to do the same thing described in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) except for the `\ndivides` symbol (both `\centernot` and `\nmid` options look weird to me for `\nmid`) but I'm doing this in a package that I want to be compatible with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX font selection using `unicode-math`.  Is using `\DeclareFontShape` the right way to do things universally?  Do I need to break this up into cases (different code for the different engines) or what?

I'd like to do things the appropriate way so it won't break with future changes to how font-selection is done or cause people to run out of math alphabets.

Comment: You're forgetting to say what symbol you want to import and from where.

Comment: What about this answer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324207  Seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: If you followed the link in my question it was clear I was talking ABOUT that answer and asking if that answer is robust and good practice in a way that I could use in a package that will be complied under pdflatex,Xelatex, lualatex with unicode-math, and without.